# Removing black box around georeferenced grayscale image in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, image, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to georeference a grayscale image (*.tif) in QGIS 2.2.0 Valmeria. It is working but QGIS draws a black box around the georeferenced raster image. If i use the option set 0 transparent, not only the black box is transparent but also the black pixels in my gray scale image. But setting black or white transparent isn't an option for me, because it is a gray scale image.

Comment: Prior to georeferencing, you can adjust the black pixels in your greyscale image slightly away from pure black to leave room for a nodata/missing data/transparency value with `gdal_translate -a_nodata 0 -scale 0 255 1 255 infile.tif outfile.tif` (assuming byte-sized pixels). This works for non-grayscale multiband data as well.

Answer (score 8):

Try converting your file to another/the same format (Raster/conversion/translate(convert format).There you can define a value for "no data", which you can set to a number different than 0.