# Changing transparency for black background when georeferencing raster

Tags: raster, georeferencing, transparency-opacity

I georeferenced a raster file and ended up with black background (exact `000000`)
The raster file contains a lot of blacks, so setting black to be a transparent color is not a good solution since I would lose the details on the raster file.

I have seen several similar questions from a few years ago. None of the answers is straightforward and works in my case. Hoping there is a better solution in more recent QGIS versions.

Comment: This might help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170362/how-do-i-eliminate-the-black-border-on-a-georeferenced-map-layer and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92458/how-to-remove-black-box-around-georeferenced-grayscale-image-in-qgis?rq=1 . Was there no nodata value defined for your raster prior to georeference?

Answer (score 4):

For me the best method is to edit the file in Photoshop (or other editor). Double click on background layer and make it a general layer. Then I select the one pixel in the right lower corner and delete this pixel, it will turn transparent. Then I save the file as TIFF with zip-compression, no layers with transparency on.
Then when you Georeference the borders will be transparent.

[image: save in photoshop]

Comment: Very nice - so in other words, if the source image has an alpha channel, so will the output image?

Answer (score 2):

The Q&A at [Removing black box around georeferenced grayscale image in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92458) helped.

Here are the detailed steps I took. If someone is not an export in QGIS, it might help.

- Upload raster in QGIS
- Apply relevant CRS
- Add transparent no data value to raster (e.g. -333333)
- Save as Geotiff
- Open the Geotiff in the Georeferencer (Do not check use 0 for transparency)
- In raster properties (add no value e.g. -333333)
  -Run the georeferencer
  and you should end up with clean file with a transparent background instead of the black background